# Doctrine (symfony) YAML schema/fixture constraint trouble

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

Morning,
I'm having some trouble creating tables/loading fixtures.
(symfony 1.4.6 with the bundled Doctrine 1.2.3(?))

Tables (simplified):

```
Horseman:
    tableName: Horseman    
    actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
    columns:
        id:     { type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: true, unsigned: true }
        name:   { type: string(100), notnull: true }

Stable:
    tableName: Stable
    actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
    columns:
        id:         { type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: true, unsigned: true }
        info:       { type: clob }
        id_owner:   { type: integer(4), unsigned: true }
    relations:
        Horseman:   { local: id_owner, foreign: id }

Horses:
    tableName: Horses
    actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
    columns:
        id:         { type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: true, unsigned: true }
        name:       { type: string(100), notnull: true }
        id_owner:   { type: integer(4), unsigned: true }
        id_stable:  { type: integer(4), unsigned: true }
    relations:
        Horseman:   { local: id_owner, foreign: id }
        Stable:     { local: id_stable, foreign: id }
```

"Horseman" doesn't have any dependencies
"Stable" has one "Horseman"
"Horses" has one "Horseman" and one "Stable"

fixtures:

```
Horseman:
    Hector:
        name: Hector

Stable:
    StableA:
        info: Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
        id_owner: Hector

Horses:
    Ed:
        name: Ed
        id_owner: Hector
        id_stable: StableA
```

When Inserting the fixtures:

```
$ php symfony doctrine:build --all --and-load
```

i get a constraint violation:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`issuetracker/Stable`, CONSTRAINT `Stable_id_owner_Horseman_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id_owner`) REFERENCES `Horseman` (`id`))
```

The "Horseman" entry gets inserted without a problem.
Inserting the other two entries by hand is not a problem either:

```
INSERT INTO Stable (id,info,id_owner,created_at,updated_at) VALUES (null,"foo",1,NOW(),NOW())
INSERT INTO Horses (id,name,id_owner,id_stable,created_at,updated_at) VALUES (null,"foo",1,1,NOW(),NOW())
```

(Does symfony save the created insert statements somewhere?)

If i get it right, Doctrine should take care of inserting orders by itself(?) Since I'm giving the correct order anyways that shouldn't be the problem..

In the hope that i just didn't see or didn't get a small thing, would one of you nice guys tell me why i get that constraint violation and/or how to fix it, pretty please..


Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
Horseman:
    Hector:
        name: Hector

Stable:
    StableA:
        info: Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
        Horseman: Hector

Horses:
    Ed:
        name: Ed
        Horseman: Hector
        Stable: StableA
```

You don't want to use an id of related object but THE related object. That's why you should use relation names rather than field names.

Comment: Works great in this example, Thanks! But how should that work if i have more than one relation to the same Table? As example: Add a second Horseman to the fixtures and a "id_previous_owner" column to Horses. How to still have Hector be the id_owner and the new Horseman be the id_previous_owner?

Comment: It finally made *bling* .. In the schema within relation you first define a relation name (not giving a table name or something). I had to give every relation a unique name (with the class: option). Thanks again (especially for the last sentence :-))